# Optimizing a MySQL query with several joins

Tags: mysql, optimization, join

One of the queries used by a web app we're running is as follows:

```
SELECT
       p.id, r.id AS report_id, tr.result_id,
       r.report_date, r.department, r.reportStatus, rs.specimen,
       tr.name, tr.value, tr.flag, tr.unit, tr.reference_range
FROM patients AS p
INNER JOIN
    patients_reports AS pr ON pr.patient_id = p.id
INNER JOIN
    reports AS r ON pr.report_id = r.id
INNER JOIN
    results AS rs ON r.id = rs.report_id
INNER JOIN
    test_results AS tr ON rs.id = tr.result_id
WHERE pr.patient_id = 17548
ORDER BY rs.specimen, tr.name, r.report_date;
```

The explain plan looks like this:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref               | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | const  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY   | 4       | const             |      1 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | rs    | ALL    | PRIMARY       | NULL      | NULL    | NULL              | 152817 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY   | 4       | demo.rs.report_id |      1 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pr    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY   | 8       | const,demo.r.id   |      1 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tr    | ref    | result_id     | result_id | 5       | demo.rs.id        |      1 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

The query returns 27371 rows.  There are 152730 rows in test_results at the moment.  This is just a small amount of demo data.

I've tried to get the query to be more efficient, but I'm having trouble getting it to execute more quickly.  I've had a look at various articles on documentation and questions on stackoverflow, but have not been able to fix this.

I tried removing one of the joins as follows:

```
SELECT
       pr.patient_id, r.id AS report_id, tr.result_id,
       r.report_date, r.department, r.reportStatus, rs.specimen,
       tr.name, tr.value, tr.flag, tr.unit, tr.reference_range
FROM patients_reports AS pr
INNER JOIN
    reports AS r ON pr.report_id = r.id
INNER JOIN
    results AS rs ON r.id = rs.report_id
INNER JOIN
    test_results AS tr ON rs.id = tr.result_id
WHERE pr.patient_id = 17548
ORDER BY rs.specimen, tr.name, r.report_date;
```

The query plan is then as follows:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref               | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | rs    | ALL    | PRIMARY       | NULL      | NULL    | NULL              | 152817 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY   | 4       | demo.rs.report_id |      1 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pr    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY   | 8       | const,demo.r.id   |      1 | Using where; Using index        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tr    | ref    | result_id     | result_id | 5       | demo.rs.id        |      1 | Using where                     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

So not much different.

I've tried rearranging the query and using STRAIGHT_JOIN amongst other things, but I'm not getting anywhere.

I'd appreciate some suggestions on how to optimize the query.  Thanks.

EDIT:  Argh!  I did not have an index on results.report_id, but it does not seem to have helped:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys     | key       | key_len | ref               | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | rs    | ALL    | PRIMARY,report_id | NULL      | NULL    | NULL              | 152817 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | eq_ref | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY   | 4       | demo.rs.report_id |      1 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pr    | eq_ref | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY   | 8       | const,demo.r.id   |      1 | Using where; Using index        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tr    | ref    | result_id         | result_id | 5       | demo.rs.id        |      1 | Using where                     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

EDIT2:

patients_reports looks like this:

```
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| patient_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| report_id  | int(11) | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

EDIT3:

After adding the results.report_id index and trying the STRAIGHT_JOIN again as suggested by @DRapp:

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
       r.id AS report_id, tr.result_id,
       r.report_date, r.department, r.reportStatus, rs.specimen,
       tr.name, tr.value, tr.flag, tr.unit, tr.reference_range
FROM patients_reports AS pr
INNER JOIN
    reports AS r ON pr.report_id = r.id
INNER JOIN
    results AS rs ON r.id = rs.report_id
INNER JOIN
    test_results AS tr ON rs.id = tr.result_id
WHERE pr.patient_id = 17548
ORDER BY rs.specimen, tr.name, r.report_date;
```

the plan looks like this:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys     | key       | key_len | ref               | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pr    | ref    | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY   | 4       | const             | 3646 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | eq_ref | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY   | 4       | demo.pr.report_id |    1 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | rs    | ref    | PRIMARY,report_id | report_id | 5       | demo.r.id         |  764 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tr    | ref    | result_id         | result_id | 5       | demo.rs.id        |    1 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

So I think that looks much better, but I'm not sure exactly how to tell.  Also the query still seems to take about the same about of time as before.

Comment: What happens if your remove the ORDER BY clause, or at least the ordering by `specimen`?  You appear to be pulling all the rows out of `results` and you don't need them all.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for 27371/152730 = ~18% of the data. Am I missing something? Full scan is very likely the fastest way to pull 18% of any data set. (There is one other answer I'm tempted to give, which is "try PostgreSQL")

Comment: @Larry Lustig: Removing the ORDER BY does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: @derobert, OK.  This particular ID is linked to a lot of the records, but others are not necessarily.  Thanks for the clue, though :)  And I am tempted to try PostgreSQL to see if it is better.  It might be an option.

Comment: @Wodin, Your "EDIT2" shows patient ID and report ID as both part of the primary key.  If the report ID is the first part, its worthless on your query as the patient is in the SECOND position.  Build ANOTHER index on JUST the Patient ID and try it.

Comment: The primary key is on (patient_id, report_id).  I'll try another index on just the patient_id, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is results.report_id indexed? It's failing to find a key and doing a table scan it looks like. I'm assuming results.id is actually the primary key.

Also, if it report_id was the primary key, and it's INNODB, it should be clustered on that index, so absolutely no clue why that isn't screaming fast if it *is* configured that way.

Comment: Thanks, I had added some indexes to get to this point, but missed the results.report_id.  It seems not to have helped, though.

Comment: How fast are we talking about? What kind of hardware? How are you benchmarking the speed to execute queries? Cold or cached?

Comment: The report_id is not the primary key.  There's an autoincrement id that's the primary key, because there are multiple results per report.  It is InnoDB.  The box is an Apple Xserve.  The "benchmarking" is just running the queries from the "mysql" command and if I run the query a few times in a row I get around 3.5s.

Comment: We'll need to do something with the primary key, INNODB does a secondary index lookup, looks that up in relation to the primary key, then the data, and I think that is what is killing you. You said: "The primary key is on (patient_id, report_id)" and "here's an autoincrement id that's the primary key", which one is it? You can also try a hash index on report_id too instead of a B-Tree being as you just want specific IDs.

Comment: Also: try dropping the primary index on the two columns and putting it on report_id only and rebuilding the clustered index using:  ALTER TABLE results ENGINE=InnoDB; This will rebuild and reorder the table and give us an idea if this road is even worth going down (or if this is the table causing lookup issues). Later you may be able to put it back as report_id, patient_id instead of the reverse (not sure if INNODB will take advantage of a cluster like that).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean about the secondary index lookup in relation to the primary key.  The (patient_id, report_id) primary key is on the patients_reports table.  The "autoincrement" primary key is on the results table.  The patients_reports table only has two columns.  The patient_id and the report_id.  I *think* the (patient_id, report_id) primary key is correct there, but let me know if you still think that's the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: report_id is a secondary index, INNODB will look that up, find the related primary key being as that is the clustered index (patient_id, report_id), THEN look up the row of data. I'd just try it because re-clustering on report_id only will give you the best performance you can get on that table for this specific lookup, if you see a drastic improvement we know it's that index/table, if not, we know to stop looking at it (clustered indexes are mind-numbingly fast, and this is the only primary index you aren't looking up).

Comment: Basically I'm trying to use storage engine behavior to get MySQL to give us data on what may be wrong (and rebuilding the patient_id, report_id primary key isn't that hard after you test this), remember to run "ALTER TABLE results ENGINE=InnoDB" to rebuild your clustered index (it will basically 'defrag' your table, so may take some time).

Answer (score 1):

I would use STRAIGHT_JOIN and go with your second query that has the patients_reports table first and secondarily join to the patient table for their name info.  Additionally, if I didn't see it, was there an index on the patients_reports table by the PATIENT_ID column either by itself, or as first element of a compound index key?

Additionally, ensure RESULTS has an index on Report_ID, same with TEST_RESULTS (index on Result_ID)

Comment: the query was not using the patient name.  The name field was from the test_results table.  So my second query removed the patients table completely since it seems it's not necessary.  I've updated the post to show how the patients_reports table is defined.  I've now added an index for results.report_id.  test_results already had an index on result_id.  I've tried the STRAIGHT_JOIN after adding the results.report_id index and that seems to have done it.

Comment: I *think* it looks better now, but the query seems not to have got any faster.